# If inside switch case

Tags: php, arrays, json, if-statement, switch-statement

```
foreach ($row as $key => $value){
switch ($key) {
case 'url';
echo "$value";
break;
case 'tipo';
echo "<div class='ear'>$value</div>";
break;
case 'data_da':
echo "dal $value ";
break;
case 'data_a':
echo "fino al $value ";
break;
case 'citta':
echo "a $value ";
break;
case 'titolo':
echo "$value ";
break;

}
```

i need to print only data_da if data_a is equal to data_da..

how can i insert an if case ? and i need also to show the datate in this format d/m/y

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your switch statement:

```
default:
    if ($data_a == $data_da) {
        echo $data_da;
    }
    break;
```

**Edit**

Hopefully after getting a better understand of your question, this is what you need.

After the foreach, put this

```
if ($row['data_da'] == $row['data_a']) {
    echo $data['data_da'];
}
```

Comment: so whit "default:" i exit from the switch case and i can use "normal" variable by the json right? thanks for help

Comment: This is not an answer and I'm not downvoting this answer, but you were comparing variables and there are no such variables within OP's loop. The `variables` that you were comparing over here were actually are `keys`

Comment: You are right, @Uchiha! @nrik, which values do you want to compare to each other?

Comment: if ($data_a == $data_da) {
        echo "il $data_da";
    }  i need this!

Comment: Perhaps you can give us an example of your data so we can better help you

Comment: the result of data_da and data_a is: DAL 2016-01-18 FINO AL 2016-01-18    ,i need to print only "il 2016-01-18" because start and end date are the same

Comment: the result whit the edit code is : {DAL 2016-01-18 {FINO AL 2016-01-18 {{{{

Comment: I omitted by mistake , this is a json_decode , I do not know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator so with a case it could be,

```
case 'data_da': 

echo  $data_a == $data_da ? " some value" : "other value";

break;
```

Or use it with your default case.

Comment: Same issue as what I had, there are no `$data_da` or `$data_a` values

Comment: so can i assign a variable name for each array data? like $data_a and $data_da?

Comment: Yes, you can, if the condition passes then you can do whatever you want.